# How to make several buttons simultaneously active but with some conditions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem. I want to make buttons section, where user can click buttons to filter some content. When user click on 'all' button, all other should be turn off (change its color to initial, not active) in this moment. Also, user can check multiple buttons.
I can't get how to do this.

Example of JSON:

```
{
    title: 'All',
    id: 53,
  },
  {
    title: 'Im a parent',
    icon: <Parent />,
    id: 0,
  },
  {
    title: 'I live here',
    icon: <ILiveHere />,
    id: 2,
  },
```

example of code: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-haze-35htx?file=/src/App.js

Its wrong, I know. I tried some solutions, but I guess I can't get how to do it correctly.

With this code I can do active multiple buttons, but I can't get how to make conditions like

if (item.title === 'all){
TURN_OFF_ANY_OTHER_BTNS
}
I guess I should store checked buttons in temporary array to make these operations.

Will be really thankfull for help.

Comment: your sandbox code is not complete. can you make it complete so that it can run without errors?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-haze-35htx?file=/src/App.js 

Its should be ok now

Comment: If roles was a dynamic variable, you could add the key for active to it and iterate over the values. I think that would solve your problem, but I'm still confused as to what you want it to do.

Comment: I want to write a condition, if the "all" button is pressed, then all the others being active should become inactive

Comment: How it would look like ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/white-cloud-wo3db?file=/src/App.js) something you would like?

```
const SocialRole = ({ item, selected, setSelected }) => {
  let style =
    [...selected].indexOf(item.id) !== -1
      ? { color: "red" }
      : { color: "blue" };
  return (
    <button
      style={style}
      onClick={() => {
        if (item.id === 53) {
          setSelected(null);
        } else {
          setSelected(item.id);
        }
      }}
    >
      {item.icon}
      <h1>{item.title}</h1>
    </button>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  // We keep array of selected item ids
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([roles[0]]);
  const addOrRemove = (item) => {
    const exists = selected.includes(item);

    if (exists) {
      return selected.filter((c) => {
        return c !== item;
      });
    } else {
      return [...selected, item];
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {roles.map((item, index) => (
        <SocialRole
          key={index}
          item={item}
          selected={selected}
          setSelected={(id) => {
            if (id === null) setSelected([]);
            else {
              setSelected(addOrRemove(id));
            }
          }}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I thought it'll be more harder than this solution

Comment: @Cabagemage If you understand this solution, and it suits your needs, then it is Ok I would say

Comment: Its really that I want to do.  I feel a little stupid. :C

Comment: @Cabagemage It is ok maybe you just need little bit more practice

Comment: The problem is, not really. I have been working with react for about a year, but I have never had to deal with similar tasks. Or I was just very tired of work that I could not come to a solution on my own. Anyway, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, I think this is what you are looking for:

```
const roles = [
  {
    title: "All",
    id: 53
  },
  {
    title: "I live here",
    id: 0
  },
  {
    title: "I live here too",
    id: 2
  }
];
// button
const SocialRole = ({ item, selected, setSelected }) => {
  const isActive = selected === item.title || selected === 'All';

  return (
    <button
      style={isActive ? { color: "red" } : { color: "blue" }}
      onClick={() => setSelected(item.title)}
    >
      {item.icon}
      <h1>{item.title}</h1>
    </button>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(roles[0].title);
  return (
    <div>
      {roles.map((item, index) => (
        <SocialRole
          key={index}
          item={item}
          selected={selected}
          setSelected={setSelected}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The problem was you were setting a new state into each button, when you should just use the state from the App.

Comment: Due to the small rating, I cannot add it to others, but a huge thank you friend!